# Caixa de texto formatada(amostra de código)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Preciso exibir uma informação na tela porém a mesma precisa ser exibida como código(javascript, c#) formatada e com cor(amostra de código), existe algum componente em jquery ou algo parecido ?

**Exemplo**

```
$('#ID').click(function (){ alert("Hello Word!")});
```

Comment: Tem aqui um exemplo de um outro colega feita com jquery UI: http://jsfiddle.net/eraj2587/Pm5Fr/14/ ... Quanto ao modificar exatamente a caixa de alert do browser (navegador) não creio que seja possível

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dê uma olhada nesse plugin: https://codemirror.net/

Ele é usado dentro de um outro plugin que eu já utilizei onde trabalho chamado Froala Editor.

Dentro do Froala Editor é o Code Mirror que cuida da identação e coloração do código html gerado. Ele tem suporte para outras linguagens também como Javascript, C#, Java e etc...

Comment: Valeu pela dica @RaphaelRosa